# Populating php drop down with additional values

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list that is generated from values in a table, however, there are two additional values I'd like to add that are not in this table.

```
$sql = mysql_query("select category_id,category_name from categories"); 
    $selection="";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $id=$row["category_id"]; 
        $category_name = $row["category_name"]; 
        $selected = ($id == $idlookup) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        $selection.="<OPTION " . $selected . " VALUE=\"$id\">".$category_name."</OPTION>";
    }

<tr><td><input type = "text" name ="search_value"></input></td><td><select name ="category"><Option >Choose Category<? echo $selection; ?></Select></td>
```

This works fine, but I'm not sure how to add two more values to the beginning of the list. How could I add the values "User" and "Group" to the beginning of this list? I do not want them in the categories table because this will only be used on one page.

Comment: 1) Stop using mysql_*, switch to PDO. 2) just echo those 2 options before while. Or add them to DB

Comment: Can you please elaborate on part 1?

Comment: just open this page and read red box http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of instantiating the variable with no content (`$selection="";`), instantiate it with this:

```
$selection="<OPTION VALUE=\"id\">User</OPTION><OPTION VALUE=\"id\">Group</OPTION>";
```

Comment: Naturally, you'll want to replace `id` with the appropriate text/number

Comment: Still have a few minutes before it'll let me.